# Ocelot dose not recognize {version}

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-5, .net-6.0, ocelot

i use ApiVersioning in Asp .net 6
my versioning work well when i use ApiSwagger but when i want to use Ocelot Api Gate Way
ocelot dose not recognize my {version} and replace {version} as string in URL

MY Orginal Api  :
http://localhost:5001/api/v1/Customer/test/1

[image]

But in Ocelot Gate Way :
http://localhost:5050/api/v{Version}/Customer/test/1

[image]

Comment: It would be explanatory if you could share api gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version should be mentioned as below

"/api/{version}/{everything}"

Check whethere it is specified like "/v{Version}". Also check {Version} or {version} (case sensitive)